# Is it possible to create this type of database for a massive forum?

Tags: database-design

Kind of like how craigslist you select a state, then a city, and you're in that community.

How do I make my forum website's home page have 2 drop menus for a state and city, then it would bring the member to a specific Forum? is this really difficult?

Please direct me to what I need to learn to make this happen!

Comment: Do you have any design in place for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can choose this option

Create on table to list all the state as below

`State` table with two columns

```
StateId - int(PK)
StateName - varchar
```

`City` table with two column as

```
CityId - int(PK)
StateId - int(FK)
StateName - varchar
```

Now you can have `User` table to save member where you add column `CityId` as 'FK' as below

```
UserId - Int/bigInt(PK)
CityId - int(FK)
..Other columns
```

Now in webpage you show list of state, and on selcting state populate city list from `City` table and on selecting city populate members.